# Applying joomla default form validation work on jQuery.choosen in joomla3.0

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla3.0

Joomla 3.0 has provided in built library for jquery.choosen. But problem in using this library is that Joomla form validation feature does not work on fields that uses jquery,choosen. Can any body help me to sort out this issue. I want to make joomla default form validation work with jQuery.choosen

Comment: Would you add an example of a field you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery choosen library not only customize but it actually hide the original select box hence the Joomla Default client side validation does not work perfectly. It is best way to use custom validation for such select boxes. Or avoid making such fields compulsary which are using jQuery.choosen library...........

Cheerssssssssssssssssss